# Applying a function to a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

Say I have a list:

```
l = {{{a, b}, c}, d}
```

I now want to apply a function, call it `F` to that list in a way that I go from the lowest to highest level, i.e.

```
F[{F[{F[{a,b}], c}] , d}]
```

Is there a function in Mathematica which does exactly that?

Comment: Why does the order for `d` and `c` change, and not for `a` and `b`?

Comment: My mistake, thank you for spotting that. I edited it.

Comment: In your example it does not matter whether `F` is applied from the lowest level up or reverse. It it matters it may affect applicable solutions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Replace[l, x_List :> F[x], All]
```

> F[{F[{F[{a, b}], c}], d}]

Also

```
ClearAll[f]
f[Except[_List, x_]] := x;
MapAll[f, l]
```

> f[{f[{f[{a, b}], c}], d}]

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility, if you want just lists to acquire the `F` wrapper:

```
l /. List -> F@*List
```

> F[{F[{F[{a, b}], c}], d}]

Answer (score 4):

```
F@*Reverse@Map[F@*Reverse, l, -2]
```

> F[{d, F[{c, F[{b, a}]}]}]

```
Fold[F[{#2, #1}] &, Flatten[l]]
```

> F[{d, F[{c, F[{b, a}]}]}]

Comment: I think that `Flatten` works in this trivial case but it will not "find" the levels in a more complex situation

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
{{{a, b}, c}, d} //. {{s_?ListQ, t_?(Not@*ListQ)} :> {f[s], t}} // f
```

It's a bit hackish because of the separate invocation of f at the end, but it returns the desired result.